# Why does on_command() event lag behind actual command?

Tags: python, discord.py

When logging user info I check who sent the command using the `on_command()` event it will print in the middle of the logs of the actual command:

```
@bot.event
@commands.has_any_role('Administrator', 'Leader', 'Moderator', 'botperms')
async def on_command(ctx):
    # Log commands
    time = "[UTC " + str(ctx.message.created_at) + "]"
    print(f'{time}\n\'{prefix}{ctx.command}\' has been used by {ctx.author.display_name} | <@{ctx.author.id}>')
    await ctx.message.delete()
    print("Deleted Command\n")
```

I have this at the very top just below `on_ready()`. Are there any suggestions on how to wait for the `on_command()` event to finish before running the command itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the event in the code doesn't matter. it's how the event works.

`on_command` and `on_command_completion` are called after the command. and therefore lags behind.

If you want a function to run before every single command, you can use the `before_invoke` decorator. You can read more about it [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_#discord.ext.commands.Bot.before_invoke).

```
@bot.before_invoke
async def command_log(ctx):
    # Log commands
    time = "[UTC " + str(ctx.message.created_at) + "]"
    print(f'{time}\n\'{ctx.command}\' has been used by {ctx.author.display_name} | <@{ctx.author.id}>')
    await ctx.message.delete()
    print("Deleted Command\n")
```